# Sequelize INNER JOIN

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to Inner Join with sequelize. I tried something but i cant understand it.Anyone help me for this ;

I have two model that are Users and Payments. I want to get Users with payments data.

I shared basicaly Example below
Anyone explain for me ? and how can i make it ?

Totaly need ' SELECT * FROM Users INNER JOIN Payments ON Users.id=Payments.user_id WHERE Users.email=?';

```js
Users.findOne({
where:{
user_email:payload.email
},
include:[{
model:Payments,
where:['Payments.user_id = Users.id']
}]
})
```

[image]

Update:
Added this.
After gived Error: Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.

```js
  Users.hasMany(Payments, { foreignKey: "user_id" });
  Payments.belongsTo(Users, { foreignKey: "id" });
```

Answer (score 5):

On your relation you can make it `required` for inner join.

```
Users.findOne({
    where: {
        user_email: payload.email
    },
    include: [{
        model: Payments,
        where: ['Payments.user_id = Users.id'],
        required: true
    }]
})
```

Comment: Hey bro;
I tried it gived me 

EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: Payments is not associated to Users!

Comment: Do you know what is this ? :)

Error: Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.

Comment: You need to associate user and payment models